# Cannot get deposit() working in simple wETH contract

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, ether, transfer

I am trying to test the `deposit()` function of the [WETH9](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2#code) contract in Remix. I compiled and deployed a simplified WETH9 contract:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.7.1;

contract WETH9 {   
    
    event Deposit(address indexed dst, uint wad);

    mapping (address => uint) public balanceOf; //get balance of WETH held by an address?

    function deposit() public payable {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

I then compiled and deployed the below Caller contract by passing in the WETH9 contract address.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.7.1;

import "./WETH9.sol";

interface IWETH9 {
    function deposit() external payable;
}

contract Caller {
    IWETH9 public weth9;

    constructor(IWETH9 _weth9){
        weth9 = _weth9;
    }

    function call_deposit() public payable {     
        weth9.deposit{ value: 50 }();
        
    }
}
```

I then called the `call_deposit()` function. This reverts at `weth9.deposit{ value: 50 }();` and results in the below error. I am not sure what the issue is. Maybe I'm not sending the right value? There's 99.9+ ETH in the vm account.

> [vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4 to: Caller.call_deposit() 0xE5f...78e22 value:
> 0 wei data: 0x374...22832 logs: 0 hash: 0x66d...ea411 transact to
> Caller.call_deposit errored: VM error: revert.
>
> revert    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note:
> The called function should be payable if you send value and the value
> you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the
> transaction to get more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing `IWETH9 _weth9` into constructor, you should pass the address of new created `WEHT9` address to constructor param, and create new IWETH in it:

```
 constructor(address weth9Address){
    weth9 = IWETH9(weth9Address);
 }
```

Additionally, the `Caller` contract should have ether beacause `weth9.deposit{ value: 50 }();` use ether of contract itself.

Comment: I rewrote the constructor as you suggested but I'm still getting the same error. Were you able to get it working in Remix (see the account balance go down? see contract balance increase? etc.?)

Comment: @gioro this line `weth9.deposit{ value: 50 }();` mean that you use 50wei of `Caller` contract to deposit and it seems that your `Caller` contract has no ether. You should transfer to address of Caller contract some Eth and retry.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem. Can you edit your solution so I can accept it. For reference: I deployed the `Caller` contract on Remix > Added 50 wei to the `Caller` contract via the "Value" field and "Transact" button in the IDE > Called `call_deposit()` again which worked.

Comment: Oh and I also had to add `receive() external payable {}` to `Caller` as fallback.

Comment: instead of hardcoding 50wei you could change to `weth9.deposit{ value: msg.sender }();`. that way the function just passes on the eth that was passed to it, and you don't have to pre-load the contract with eth before calling the function.

Comment: Thanks sola24, I believe you mean `value: msg.value`, which passes the value from the `msg.sender` to `Caller` to `WETH9` and increments the ETH balance of the `Caller` contract in `WETH9` with the way things are currently written.